# Which storage option for preserving app data in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, cloud, storage, android-contentprovider

I do not want the data that is fed into the android app by the user to go away when the app is uninstalled or the device is lost/disposed. What I necessarily want is - data has to be tied to a user account rather than a device where the user can install the app from any other android device by logging into his account using his login credentials and see all the data that was entered in the past from an old/other device. Please suggest a storage option that would best fit for this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very generic question and I think someone might vote to close it but I will still attempt a generic answer.

Essentially you want the data saved on some external data storage (not on device). So the obvious thing is a server. You will need to set up a machine and run a server on it which can communicate with your app. Also you will need to have unique id for each user (authentication?) which will link user-data with the user, so that if user uninstalls and reinstalls your app, the app can then download the user's data from the server to the mobile device on which the app is running.

For the server you can look at Amazon AWS, Google App Engine, Heroku etc. You can set up a minimal server at one of these places, maybe set a DB there (SQL/ NoSQL) and get a unique URL so that the app can ping the server (so static IP obviously). Then your app can send network requests to your server fetch data for a user and save it to the app whenever the user wants it (say on reinstall, device change, monthly etc).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, it does. I agree it is a generic question. I couldn't find anything straightforward when I searched for it. Most answers talked about what options available and not much about which of those options can preserve the data. This is helpful for a beginner like me. Thank you!

Comment: @sunskin No problem. Do follow up if you have any other specific questions as you progress in this. Also, it would be awesome if you could accept my answer! :)

Comment: Please share your opinion on AWS Cognito

Comment: To be honest I have never used AWS Cognito, for that matter I have hardly used AWS but from other experiences I can tell you that AWS Cognito may handle your problem but not give you customizability. If you have done backend development then having a server and writing your own backend code to do what AWS Cognito is doing would not be too difficult. So its really a tradeoff. You want customizability or easier deployment. If the latter go for Cognito.

Answer (score 1):

Google is working on [Google Cloud Save](https://developer.android.com/google/gcs/index.html) as a simple way to save data to the cloud on an Android app. There is no backend programming needed.

It's in closed beta now, so that's not super helpful right away, but it might open up to the public soon.